# Error occurred while running .getAttribute() command on <csselement>: TypeError: _this2.client.assertion is not a function

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

While creating nightwatch tests, I used `waitForAttribute()` and it works with nightwatch@0.9.0. But when I tried to upgrade to the nightwatch@1.0.6, it gives following error:

```
An error occurred while running .getAttribute() command on <.csselement>: TypeError: _this2.client.assertion is not a function
  at /node_modules/nightwatch-custom-commands-assertions/js/commands/waitForAttribute.js:100:19
  at NightwatchAPI.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/nightwatch-custom-commands-assertions/js/commands/waitForAttribute.js:117:13)
  at transport.locateElement.then.then.result (../node_modules/nightwatch/lib/api-loader/element-command.js:107:23)
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
   at <anonymous>
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
   at <anonymous>
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```